# ¿Por qué Django devuelve los comandos para acceder a la base de datos cuando añado una plantilla a una función de visualización?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Queria ser capaz de modificar un articulo, entonces modifiqué `views.py`:

```
def viewtodo(request, todo_pk):
    # grab the todo from the primary key
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk)
    form = TodoForm(instance=Todo)
    return render(request, 'todo/viewtodo.html', {'todo':todo, 'form':form})
```

Pero me dedevuelve cosas extranas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    memo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Aqui esta el contenido de `viewtodo.html`:

```
{% extends 'todo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{ todo.title }}

<form action="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Adjunta el form `TodoForm` y el template que renderisa la vista `viewtodo`.

Comment: @JulioCesar Si, acabo de adjuntarlo

Comment: Tienes que mostar cómo estás renderizando los objetos en tu template. Es decir, el contenido de `viewtodo.html`

Comment: @César Sí, me lo acabo de poner. Siento llegar tarde. Hago Django realmente sólo por divertirme :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que le estás pasando a tu formulario la clase del modelo, es decir, `Todo`, en vez de la instancia `todo`:

```
def viewtodo(request, todo_pk):
    # grab the todo from the primary key
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk)
    form = TodoForm(instance=Todo) # TIENES QUE PASAR LA INSTANCIA
    return render(request, 'todo/viewtodo.html', {'todo':todo, 'form':form})
```

Lo corrijes pasándole al formulario el objeto correcto:

```
form = TodoForm(instance=todo) # La instancia que obtienes con el get_object_or_404
```